# Scrapoxy install error using docker

Tags: docker

While trying to get started with Scrapoxy as per the instructions [here](http://docs.scrapoxy.io/en/master/quick_start/index.html), I had followed the instructions until step 3A.  However, when I run docker using the command specified under step 3A, I get an error which keeps repeating. Below is the error, along with the outputs preceding it each time it shows up:

```
2017-11-08T22:24:51.804Z - debug: [Manager] checkInstances
2017-11-08T22:24:52.515Z - debug: [Manager] adjustInstances: required:1 / actual:0
2017-11-08T22:24:52.515Z - debug: [Manager] adjustInstances: add 1 instances
2017-11-08T22:24:52.515Z - debug: [ProviderAWSEC2] createInstances: count=1
2017-11-08T22:24:53.225Z - debug: [ProviderAWSEC2] createInstances: actualCount=0
2017-11-08T22:24:54.045Z - error: [Manager] Error: Cannot update or adjust instances: InvalidParameterValue: Value () for parameter groupId is invalid. The value cannot be empty
    at Request.extractError (/usr/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/ec2.js:50:35)
    at Request.callListeners (/usr/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (/usr/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/usr/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:615:14)
    at Request.transition (/usr/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/usr/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:617:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/usr/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
    at Request.emit (/usr/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/usr/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:615:14)
    at Request.transition (/usr/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/usr/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/scrapoxy/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
```

When I open the Scrapoxy GUI (as per step 4 in the Quick Start guide linked to above), no instances are shown, which I expected, based on the output shown above.  Step 6 in the quickstart returns an error saying `scrapoxy: command not found`

How can I remedy this, so I can use Scrapoxy?  I would like to integrate it with the python library Scrapy.

(I am using Ubuntu 16.04, if it matters.  Docker is already installed and functional.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What's wrong with your step 3A

- Reference: [Scrapoxy Issue NO.70](https://github.com/fabienvauchelles/scrapoxy/issues/70)
- Make sure your AWS instance met following criterias:

  - It's located in **eu-west1** region
  - You have create a security group in **eu-west1** region

### What's wrong with your step 3B

- You didn't install scrapoxy properly.
- Here is an example of how to install scrapoxy on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (tested on Linode)

  - You should first install `nodejs` on your Ubuntu 16.04 via

    ```
    sudo apt-get update
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -
    sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
    ```
  - Then Install Make and Scrapoxy:

    ```
    sudo apt-get install -y build-essential && sudo npm install -g scrapoxy
    ```
  - Generate Configuration:

    ```
    scrapoxy init conf.json
    ```
  - Install your favorite Text Editor(Vim or etc..)
  - Edit configuration

    - Edit `conf.json`
    - In the `commander` section, replace `password` by a password of your choice
    - In the `providers/awsec2` section, replace `accessKeyId`, `secretAccessKey` and `region` by your AWS credentials and parameters.
  - Start Scrapoxy

    ```
    scrapoxy start conf.json -d
    ```
  - Connect GUI Interface:

    ```
    http://server-ip:8889
    ```

Comment: It was originally my understanding that 3A and 3B were mutually exclusive, as one describes using Scrapoxy with Docker and the other describes using Scrapoxy without Docker.  I guess this is not the case.  Thank you.

Comment: @JohiasburgFrowell to me it is still very confusing after hours of trying... I setup a new user with creds as well as a security group on aws. 2) Then I started the docker image locally. 3) I copied the AMI and started an instance out of it. What do I have to do more in step 3B? Do I have to spin up another instance? Isn't it scrapoxy again? Did you create another docker image? How did you solve it? Please help me ...